# How can i use different source files with same class name in Xcode for mocking?

Tags: xcode, xcode-scheme

My Xcode project contains two target:

- main that contain the main source code
- uiTest that contain code for ui testing

So it has a file called `DIResolver` that used to provide my dependencies.
When i build main target it works fine but when i start UI tests i need to mock some dependencies.

The main question is: can i use the same filename in two different place (`real` and `mock` for example) resolving by scheme and how?